# Amazon Corretto 11 docker image for windows container

Tags: docker, windows-container, corretto

I am looking for an image of Amazon Corretto 11 (JRE only) specifically for windows container, as I have to run it on Windows Server. I tried looking for it in the docker repo https://hub.docker.com/_/amazoncorretto but couldn't find one. Is there any other repository which provides Corretto JRE only docker images for windows containers?

Answer (score 0):

If you check their github page for Coretto-Docker . you can see there is no windows container version  Docker file which means they don't have an ofifical image . Your options are

- Running Linux containers under Windows Server through Docker (i asumme you use Docker Runtime)
- Get their Linux alpine Docker file and change the base image to nano-server and change relevant directives for windows . You can see Corretto 11 JRE Docker file under here . you can build your version.

https://github.com/corretto/corretto-docker/blob/master/11/jre/alpine/Dockerfile

Comment: Most recipes for running Linux containers on Windows Server refer to LinuxKit LCOW, which was an experimental feature and now is a frozen project. Mirantis Container Runtime (MCR) seems to be only able to run Windows containers on Windows Servers.